# can i make abstract class a child of normal class in java

Tags: java

Is it possible to make an abstract class a child of normal class? Please answer with a code or a scenario if it is possible. 
like this.
class A
{
}

abstract class B extends A
{
}

Comment: Actually IMO, this is a good question if it is rephrased and ask for a valid situation for abstract class to extend a concrete class instead of asking a question which can be easily verified with a compiler.

Comment: that is why i m asking the situation in my question

Comment: You may want to change the title of your question accordingly. Not everyone will answer according to what they feel you want to ask. Many will just answer based on what they see on the question. +1 anyway and I don't see anyone answer this in SO with an example before.

Comment: Instead of writing this question why not try compiling the code you included in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to make an abstract class a child of normal class? Please answer with a code or a scenario if it is possible. like this. class A { }
>
> abstract class B extends A {

Yes, it is entirely possible. Being made abstract does not prevent it from extending from a concrete class.

The general idea of abstract class is to provide common properties and behaviours (especially behaviours to be implemented individually in its subclass). However being made abstract only prevent itself from instantiation.

It is still logical if I want to inherit some properties from a concrete class to an abstract class even though this scenario is rare.

---

**A simple (or rather curde) example:**

In my honest opinion this is a very uncommon scenario. However, let me try to give you an example with as much relevance as possible.

Imagine having a concrete class: **`Person`**

```
class Person
{
    String name;  //every person has name
    int age;      //every person has age

    //constructors & other methods not shown
}
```

And you have an abstract class: **`Student`**
The Student class is made abstract with its potential subclass in mind: `Part-Time Student` and `Full-Time Student`.

```
abstract class Student
{
    String name;    //every student has name
    int age;        //every student has age
    int grade;      //every student has a current grade (level of studies)

    //constructors & other methods not shown
}
```

---

Since every **`Student`** is also a **`Person`** with `name` and `age`, I could possible do this:

```
abstract class Student extends Person
{
    //name & age inherited
    int grade;

    //constructors & other methods not shown
}
```

The above is probably not the best class design we can have and it is argumentative that we can rearrange the above classes such that the abstract class is at the top of the hierarchy , but this is just one simple example portraying the idea where abstract class may still inherit properties from a concrete class.

Comment: @Ra's Al Ghul  I've updated my answer. You may take a look. There could be other reason and scenario where you will be doing this, but frankly speaking it is hard to think of such scenario until we are stuck in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is. You already provided the valid code in your question. Why didn't you check it before asking?

Comment: nice question asked in the end...:), we have IDE and before asking questions its really good to do it ourselves and then if some thing is not clear then one should ask question, although there are no bad questions and each question should be honored but still each question should be backed up by some self effort.

Comment: I ask this because some one told me that it is impossible and I myself can't find any scenario to implement it

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it. An abstract class can extend another **non final** class   having at least one **non private constructor**. Class declared `abstract` can further be extended to provide concrete implementation of the `abstract APIs` (methods).

Intent of `abstract` class is to declare **abstract contracts**. These are provided by the signature of the abstract methods (methods with only signature and no body and declared with keyword `abstract`).  Other classes extend the abstract class and provide the concrete implementation to the abstract methods as per the java doc and signature declared in the base abstract class.